# Table of dark souls II casting speeds for spells.

Tags: dark-souls-2

I've been trying to find casting speeds for spells. I've been pvping and good melee pvp people are able to dodge spells 100% of time time, and can chase me down and stab me for free. I'd like to add a spell with high casting speed to put pressure and stop the abusive free stabs caused by my low casting times.
I've been googling a lot, and i have not found any casting times charts. This is a kind of resource that would be published by the developers of the game. I don't think anyone has this kind of info. Anyway to find it? Should i just time every spell of the game myself?

Comment: WOTG and Force can probably help there, very quick self AoE can almost stun lock and (in case if WOTG) sometimes kill the player.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a complete answer, but i'll just post my personal experience.
As @ben said, WOTG and Force are spell you're probably searching for (they are both actually miracles).

Also, if you like pyromancy, Forbidden Sun has a nice casting speed, great for punishing flask/heal abuse.

Anyway, you probably should focus on items that increase your casting speed, for example the Lion Mage Set or the Clear Bluestone Ring.

Other than that, as far as my experience goes, spells have pretty much the same casting speed.

You could try to punish the free stab tactics with Homing Soul Mass.

Answer (score 0):

Things to keep in mind when wanting to increase casting speed:

**Attunement**

Attunement not only increases your number of spell slots, curse resistance, agility, but also is the main stat that increases the speed of casts. Actually it's twice as fast as increasing Intelligence or Faith. I think increasing 1 attunement level is equivalent to increasing 1 Intelligence level and 1 Faith level (as far as cast speed goes).

There are also several piece of armor/clothing that increase cast speed:

**Black Hood**: Increases cast speed by 13 points. Also increases Intelligence and Faith levels by 2 each.

**King's Crown**: Increases cast speed by 4 point. Also increases Intelligence and Faith by 3 levels each.

**Lion Mage set**: Each of the 3 pieces in this set increase your casting speed by 5.2% rounding **DOWN** to the nearest **WHOLE** value. Meaning each piece gives 5% for a total of 15.6% aka 15%